# touch and hold = hover on iPad - procedure and philosphy

Tags: jquery, ipad

In google mail (gmail), you can move your mouse over the "Send" Button, and a little dialog balloon pops up that says "Apple-Enter to submit".

there is no hover on an iPad or similar.  I am considering using jQuery for a class of elements say .touchAndHold which will allow a touch-and-hold to be construed as a hover instead.  I believe I could implement this particular feature without much effort (based on jQuery and my knowledge of it).  However I am wondering if there is any code that is available already, none found yet.

Also wonder if there are any embedded HTML or javascript methods or structures so I don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery-Mobile? I haven't, but my assumption is that it automates these kinds of mappings for you.

Comment: or it provides new events that you can bind for mobile gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Mobile and bind the [`taphold`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) event:

```
$("#sendButton").on("taphold hover", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: two questions on this 1) by simply adding return false; to my function end, this would prevent the default click behavior correct? - and 2) this is functionally equivalent to onhover, so is there any way to avoid writing the same codeblock within this function() as on('hover', .. function(){ }) ?

Comment: Yes, `return false;` should always prevent the default action. I've update the answer to show how to handle multiple events with the same code.